# Cubes in Cuboids

Tags: c, clang

Helo everybody,

I need a C program to calculate the minimum amount of cuboids of size `A` by `B` by `C` to house a `N` cubes of side length `S`, where `1 <= N <= pow(10, 9)`, `1 <= S <= min(A, B, C)`, `1 <= A, B, C <= 1000`. I did the following:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned long long int cubenum, length, boxnum, a, b, c, cpb;
    
    scanf("%llu %llu %llu %llu %llu", &cubenum, &length, &a, &b, &c); getchar();
    
    // how many cubes per box?
    cpb = a/length * b/length * c/length;
    
    // how many boxes given the amount of cubes?
    boxnum = (cubenum + (cpb - 1)) / cpb;
    
    printf("%llu\n", boxnum);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The following testcases are given:

```
testcase #1
stdin: 24 4 8 8 8
stdout: 3

testcase #2
stdin: 27 3 8 4 10
stdout: 5
```

I added the following testcases myself:

```
testcase #3
stdin: 1 1 1 1 1
stdout: 1

testcase #4
stdin: 1000000000 500 999 999 999
stdout: 1000000000

testcase #5
stdin: 1000000000 499 999 999 999
stdout: 125000000

testcase #6
stdin: 1000000000 2 999 999 999
stdout: 9
```

I compiled with Clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1. The given testcases passed correctly on my device, and the ones I added myself seem correct when doing the math manually, however upon submission my program was declared "wrong". Unfortunately, there isn't any feedback as to where, why, or how it failed. The compiler the jury uses is unknown, however my past experience tell me it's likely running Linux (I tried using a Windows specific library function). Therefore, I would like to know, are there any test cases where my code would fail that I haven't caught? Or are there other oversights that I have made?

Thank you for your time.

---

Side question:

The part I suspect I am getting wrong is here:

```
boxnum = (cubenum + (cpb - 1)) / cpb;
```

I have tried using `ceil()` in `math.h`, but it feels really hacky with the `double` casts and then back to `unsigned long long int`, but it does work on all the testcases. I had to compile with `clang -lm main.c -o main` instead of `clang main.c -o main`, but it did run. Could it be that the jury has a modified `math.h` lib? On a different program, I used `sqrt()` and `pow()` and they were both accepted as correct, which tells me either the problem isn't where I suspect it to be, or that the jury indeed does have a modified `math.h` lib. Or could it be something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
cpb = a/length * b/length * c/length;
```

is wrong because this expression is calculated from left to right and truncation may not work well for `b` and `c`.

For example, with this input

```
15 10 100 10 19
```

The formula will be calculated like

```
  a/length * b/length * c/length
= 100/10 * 10/10 * 19/10
= 10 * 10 / 10 * 19 / 10
= 100 / 10 * 19 / 10
= 10 * 19 / 10
= 190 / 10
= 19
```

Therefore, your program will output `1` because the required 15 cubes can be covered by 19 cubes while the correct output is `2` because actually only 10 cubes can be created from one box.

Try this:

```
cpb = (a/length) * (b/length) * (c/length);
```

Comment: Thank you! This was absolutely the problem. If you don't mind, how exactly does "truncation may not work well" for b `b` and `c`?

Comment: @404NameNotFound The number multiplied will also be multiplied to the part which should be truncated and it will make the resulting number greater than needed result. Example: `2 * (5/2) = 2 * 2 = 4` while `2 * 5/2 = 10 / 2 = 5` (extra 1 is added!). This can be seen as `2 * 5/2 = 2 * 2.5 = 2 * (2 + 0.5) = 2 * 2 + 2 * 0.5 = 4 + 1 = 5` while it should be `2 * trunc(5/2) = 2 * trunc(2.5) = 2 * 2 = 4`.